# Overload typescript interface

Tags: typescript, interface, overloading

Why this error?

I'm trying to overload with typescript, I've read the documentation. But, I can't identify the error. Someone to save?

```
export declare type TCallbackResponse<T> = ICallbackResponse<T>;

export type ICallbackResponse<T = string> = {
    (arg1: T, arg2: T, arg3: T): Promise<void>;
    (arg1: T, arg2: T): Promise<void>;
}


function handle<T = string>(name: string, call: ICallbackResponse<T>): void {

}

async function message(pattern: string, channel: string, message: string): Promise<void>
async function message(channel: string, message: string): Promise<void> {
    
}

async function pmessage(pattern: string, channel: string, message: string): Promise<void> {

}

handle('message', message) // Argument of type '(pattern: string, channel: string, message: string) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ICallbackResponse<string>'.(2345)
handle('message', pmessage) // Argument of type '(pattern: string, channel: string, message: string) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ICallbackResponse<string>'.(2345)
```

Link to the code: https://www.typescriptlang.org/pt/play?#code/LAKApgHgDg9gTgFwAQBMwGMA2BDOYkICeU+AKgMLaaYBG26A1gEpgDOsAdq2ADykB8SALxIAkpWp1GLdjC68BAblChIsRAWL5xVWvWZtO3PsKSsEcAJYcA5oJEBvUEhdIAFLhsBGAFxJSADRIngBMfoHBcDYAzOEAlH4ACnAwALaWxgBuMJYo-Mogru6evv5BofFJKelZOXkFoAC+KiCgAGYArhzoCJZySAAW2BwomAqm5la2-G4c2KlgfpPWNkHoun46kvoyRgr8CUjZuUhOrSDN59ishN1Ind29-QusrNg2YG5Q2AgIYHAcJYWFZrIYcDhgTBAqarJAvN4faErQ7JNIZXjHPKga63dD3Lo9PocOFsBGfdBgiFQszA2xBeHvRY0mEo6roniYwRnIpNFo4u4PQn9KAMj5fH5-AFIulICnDKnS2GipnLWystG1XJclqXUBg0afADkysN9NJjLieuGBrcxvNH1NSBF9rAlpAQA

Comment: There's a bit too much extraneous stuff going on in this code example for it to be a good [mcve].  What is the purpose of the unused `TCallbackResponse` declaration?  What is the purpose of the generic `T` type parameters which are only ever specified as their default `string` type?  Would your question be essentially the same with [this code example](https://tsplay.dev/m3ALjw) instead?  Then, I'm not quite sure why you would want to overload a function that way; why not just write `(x: string, y: string, z?: string) => Promise<void>`? What will `handle()` do with `call`?

Comment: Because the callback theree are the others parameters. In message function, she to return two parameters, ```channel: string, message: string```

And the other three, ```pattern: string, channel: string, message: string```

Comment: Sorry; I don't understand.  Perhaps there is a language barrier?  Please demonstrate, preferably with code, a situation where `(arg1: string, arg2: string, arg3?: string) => Promise<void>` is not preferable to `ICallbackResponse<string>`.  Also, it doesn't seem that you addressed most of my questions.  Could you please [edit] your question to include a genuine [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#overload-signatures-and-the-implementation-signature), In your case below two methods are called the **Implementation Signatures** not the **Overload signatures** -

```
async function message(channel: string, message: string): Promise<void> {
    
}

async function pmessage(pattern: string, channel: string, message: string): Promise<void> {

}
```

From Documentation -

> The signature of the implementation is not visible from the outside.
> When writing an overloaded function, you should always have two or
> more signatures above the implementation of the functions.

As you have multiple call signatures and not all the calls are matching ***all the signatures in*** ***ICallbackResponse*** , due to the above fact note that there are no signatures matching the with `(arg1: T, arg2: T): Promise<void>;` *observe the missing third parameter.*

On a side note, by looking closely in your case, you dont even need the `(arg1: T, arg2: T): Promise<void>;` type in the `ICallbackResponse`.